# How do I certify a windows printer driver? Or can I skip the certification?

Tags: printing, driver, xps

I have successfully created an XPS Printer Driver for windows with windows driver kit. The printer part (driver and actual printer setup) is a part of a larger application. To install the driver manually works fine since I can manually accept that it is not certified when windows prompt me to accept or decline the installation for that reason (that it is not certified).

The driver installation should be embedded in a Click once installation together with another application, but that does not seem to work so well since I never get the chance to accept the fact that the driver is not certified. The installation just "hangs" when getting to the printer installation part.

Has someone else encountered these kinds of problems and either know how to get the driver certified or knows a better way of not needing to certify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to work with Microsoft on this. In order to get the driver certified, you need to pass their WHQL tests. Some more information at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463010
This can be a painful and expensive process at times, so I wish you luck.

Comment: hmm... nice. The H in WHQL is for "Hardware" right? I need to do this even though it is a virtual printer, without hardware, I suppose. (Sorry for not mentioning that in my previous post)

Comment: @Stig Yes, the H is for hardware. I don't believe that the driver being a virtual printer makes much difference (the tests are focused more on ensuring that the driver is stable than the actual printer). I may be wrong about this though - I've only developed drivers for actual printers. Maybe you can change your install method instead so that the user is prompted to accept the uncertified driver?

Comment: thank you. That is actually so simple that I did not think of it. I'll go with that. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: @Jon, I'm looking for how painful this process is. I opened a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434335/how-painful-is-the-whql-certification-process

Answer (score 0):

You can use printUI.dll which is a printer/driver install utility for installing using a script. This link gives some details of the DLL 
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189105.

Also search in google for PrintUI.DLL and you will get the reference manual. Using this you can install drivers having an INF file (which will basically be the format of your XPS driver package, I assume). These have some flags /q and /Gw for quiet modes which *should* suppress the driver warnings.

Hope this helps. If so (+1) :)

Comment: I'll check the details and see if I can simplify and get through with the installation this way.

Comment: In win7x64 no combination of /q and /gw succesfully installs an unsigned driver (at least for me). It looks like when windows can't display the unsigned ui prompt it just assumes you clicked "don't install". and then printui errors out.